# Reference for generalized ind-completions?

Tags: ct.category-theory, enriched-category-theory

I am wondering whether any enriched versions of ind- and pro- completions have been studied? I can not find any literature on them, even though I believe people (most likely the Australian school) must have cared about them in the previous years.

I would be grateful for any reference.

Comment: Have you looked at [Kelly, _Structures defined by finite limits in the enriched context_] or [Borceux and Quinteriro, _Enriched accessible categories_]?

Answer (score 2):

The recent series of papers by Lack and Tendas are good references for enriched accessible categories:

- [Flat vs. filtered colimits in the enriched context](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.08612) (Lack–Tendas)
- [On continuity of accessible functors](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.14192) (Tendas)
- [Virtual concepts in the theory of accessible categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.11056) (Lack–Tendas)
- [Accessible categories with a class of limits](https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.07135) (Lack–Tendas)

You can also find relevant older references among the citations in these papers.